# implication of private in C

Tags: c++, c

What is the implication of "private unsigned char" in C?

Comment: I believe C does not support access specifiers like private, protected and public

Comment: there is no access specifiers in C, and also the syntax is not correct

Answer (score 9):

The probable implication of 'private' in C is that you have a macro that defines private as something, possibly:

```
#define private static
```

There is no keyword 'private' in pure (standard) C.  You might be using a C++ compiler (in which case there are all sorts of caveats about what private is used for), or you might be using some non-standard extension in your compiler.

Comment: gcc is makes a very clear distinction between C and C++, Borland and Microsoft far less so.